# Salt additions to the glass

Tags: ingredients, water, taste, chemistry

So here's my predicament: I've realized that my city water has low Chloride levels compared to the sulfates (i.e. the sulfate/chloride ratio is higher than ideal). Reading that this might be the case, I measured out the approx. amount of CaCl2 to be added to one of my already bottled beers. I poured the beer into a glass and added the salt. Waited for the salt to dissolve, and tasted the beer. This resulted in a much smoother, fuller body beer with less bitter-dry assertiveness in the finish. (beer types: Hefeweizen and Weizenbock)

I have several batches of beer that are already bottled that could use some CaCl2. The CaCl2 from my local homebrew store appears to be anhydrous, so I can't simply measure out the appropriate amount of salt per bottle and add this as needed to each glass because the salt starts pulling water from the air and making a mess of things.

This brings me to my question: Can I simply measure out the several separate amounts of the required CaCl2 additions per bottle and mix these with very small amounts of filtered water and store these in some small vials? This would allow me to some homebrew to some friends with a small vial of liquid salt addition to be added to the glass.

Would this work, or am I changing the CaCl2 by adding water? (I'm no chemist) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably simpler to prepare a solution with CaCl2. For every gram of CaCl2, take 2 gram of distilled, demineralised or reverse osmosis water. Mix well, so you obtain a solution of 33% (W/W) CaCl2. Then, if you know the amount you used for adding to your bottles, take 3 times the amount of solution.

I am pretty sure it will only be drops that you will need, I use the same solution for my brewing liquors, and the amount I need for 15 litre is about 3 ml.

Answer (score 0):

I heard in some podcast that you can add your salt additions to the fermenter, so why not the bottled beer. When you bottle from a bottling bucket, maybe add the salts to this. Should be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but these are a few batches that have already been bottled. Moving forward, i will be adding salt additions to my mash or boil.